# Vue unable to load SignalR Core with Typescript

Tags: typescript, web, vue.js, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR Core in my Vue application together with `@vue/cli` and Typescript. In my component, I simply use

```
import signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
```

and the compilers tells me all is well. Both `npm run serve` and `npm run build` tell me everything is ok. However, once I try to load my app in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'signalR' of undefined
```

This happens at the very beginning of the contents of signalr.js:

```
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
(global.signalR = factory());
}
```

It seems that for some reason `global` is undefined. Is there a problem in the way I'm importing libraries in Vue, or has the SignalR team improperly exported their classes?

I've also tried `const signalR = require("./signalr.js")`, but that gives me sort of the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the culprit was

```
import signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
```

If I don't use the catch-all import and import just the types I need, it works fine:

```
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from "@aspnet/signalr";
```

There's probably something wrong with how `signalR` is exported, but I don't know what.